# Robot is prize for winning arcade game, then tries to kill everyone?

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction, horror

A local teen gets the high score on an arcade game, and he wins a real life replica of the main enemy in the game. It arrives at his door one day. At first he and his (I'm pretty sure girlfriend, maybe sister?) are enamoured with it, but then it tries to kill them and their friends and family. There is one scene I remember where the robot picks up a long kitchen knife in its arm, and it rotates quickly.

I thought the movie was called "Hover" for some reason, but that's not it. The robot was short and red I think.

Comment: @Walt Why is the 2014 marked as a duplicate of the 2016 question, rather than the other way around?

Comment: @StigHemmer Discussed [here](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2468/why-was-my-old-question-was-marked-as-a-duplicate-of-a-newer-question) (and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147651/259499)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not "Hover" but [Evolver](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112993/), (1995).

> A popular virtual-reality video game gets ported to real life, and
>   Kyle, one of the best Evolver players in the US, gets the opportunity
>   to try playing against a little robot version of the arcade game.
>   However, Evolver is programmed to win at all costs, and the match
>   between Kyle and Evolver gradually becomes a frantic struggle for
>   survival.

Comment: That's definitely it, thanks! Cannot believe this starred Ethan Embry and I completely forgot. This must part of a subliminal reason I like him so much.